# PHP multilanguage site with cookie

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want to make a multilanguage site with PHP based on COOKIE.

I try with this code but every time the page is refreshed, the language changes:

header.php

```
<div class="header-language">
<?php
    foreach ($lingue as $k=>$v)
    {
         if ($k != $lingua)
         {
             setcookie("lang", $k, time() + (86400 * 7), '/');
             ?>
             <a href=""><img src="bandiere/<?php echo $flags[$k]; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $v; ?>" title="<?php echo $v; ?>" border="0" /></a>
             <?php
         }
    }
?>
</div>
```

gestore.php

```
<?php 
$lingue = array(1=>'Italiano', 'English'); 
$choose = array(1=>'Scegli la lingua', 'Choose language'); 
$flags  = array(1=>'it', 'uk');

$lingua = $_COOKIE['lang'];

switch ($lingua)
{
    case 1:
        include "lingue/it.php";
        break;
    case 2:
        include "lingue/uk.php";
        break;
}
?>
```

cookie.language.php

```
<?php 
$cookie_name = "lang"; 
$cookie_value = 1; 
//Check if there is already the cookie
if(!isset($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
    //Create the language cookie
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 7), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

Anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: in header.php you don't check for the actual value in the cookie, do you?

Comment: and can you clarify which script gets included when and where?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` paste that into your files and tell us what you get back, *per favore* (please).

Comment: http://hiphopneverdies.altervista.org

this is the site where I use the GET method to change the language, and it works, but now I want to use COOKIE instead of the GET.